# How Can I get todays date from a URL query string

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add a query string to a URL for a survey tool that may provide today's date in a hidden field in the survey.

I am unable to add any code to the HTML section of the survey but was hoping to use something on the lines of;

www.thisismysurvey.com?todaysdate=******

This is my first foray into coding and query strings and my first question on Stack Overflow so please be gentle with me if I've overlooked something obvious.

Cheers,

Comment: Can you inject JS to the survey page?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the query string using javascript

```
var params = window.location.search.substring(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, in JQuery your URL is contained in a variable called window.location.href

In your example window.location.href = www.thisismysurvey.com/?todaysdate=**

Melvinr's answer match your question, but a more generic solution would be a function getting params by name

```
$.getParam = function(name){
  var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
  //returns 0 if there is no param matching the name
  return results[1] || 0;
}
```

The regular expression will only catch the value between "name=" and the next parameter.

Then call it like this

```
var todaysdate = $getParam('todaysdate');
```

Hope it helps